# How To Deny Access To File But Allow Server

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, geolocation, authorization

I have a web application that has a configuration folder that houses multiple XML files that are configuration settings for multiple "portals" as you will.  I need IIS to have access to them so the "portal" loads (sql connection strings, master page paths) but I want to deny any outside access (url browsing).  Here's an example below:

http://www.mywebsite/virtualdirectory/configurationdirectory/configfile.xml

I need to restrict access to this file if you're browsing to it but still allow the system access to it so it can parse the "portal" that it's loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Allow PHP file to be requested by javascript but not directly from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7772591/367456)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a [rewrite rule](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)

You can also do this with a [Request Filtering rule](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/filteringRules/filteringRule/appliesTo)

Answer (score 0):

If the website doesn't need to serve XML files to the end user then remove it as a MIME type.

Comment: This DOES cure the problem that I'm having but I went with Conrad's answer because I might want to serve XML files in another directory and/or setup security different.  If I remove it as a MIME value, then I can't access it anywhere.  But, thanks for the answer.  This works too!

Comment: No problemo. You could also remove the MIME value for just that folder.